# Map not updating after permission to use location services is given

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have an MKMap. When the user logs onto the app for the first time, it asks to use location services. My problem is that if the user clicks ok, the map doesn't update, and doesn't go to their location. If the user leaves the view and comes back, the map works. How would I fix this.

I have tried this with no success -

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {

    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {

        AMBlurView *mapBlurred = [AMBlurView new];
        mapBlurred.frame = self.view.bounds;
        [self.view addSubview:mapBlurred];

        MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(52.0f,80.0001f);
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = {37.7833, 122.4167};
        MKCoordinateRegion region = {coordinate, span};

        MKCoordinateRegion regionThatFits = [self.schoolMap regionThatFits:region];
        NSLog(@"Fit Region %f %f", regionThatFits.center.latitude, regionThatFits.center.longitude);

        [self.schoolMap setRegion:regionThatFits animated:YES];

        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.schoolTextBlur];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.autocompleteTableView];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.schoolText];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.theLine];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.theLine2];

        [self showLocationUnavailable];


    }
    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {

        MKUserLocation *myLocation = [self.schoolMap userLocation];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [[myLocation location] coordinate];
        MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 9000, 9000);
        [self.schoolMap setRegion:region animated:YES];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this as soon as the user gives permission to get the location it's quite likely that `[self.schoolMap userLocation]` hasn't got a good location yet. Instead you could set the map to followUserLocation when the user grants permission as that will keep the map looking at where the user is, or turn on a CLLocationManager that will keep triggering the `didUpdateUserLocation` delegate method until you get an accurate fix and then tell it to stop.

Comment: In addition to the CLLocationManager delegate methods, the [MKMapViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MKMapViewDelegate) protocol includes several methods for responding to user location updates, such as `mapViewWillStartLocatingUser:` and `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:`.